# How to mint an NFT using `/sign_url` REST API of NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

We're building a Marketplace in NEAR blockchain. Currently, integrating the mint feature.

We have build a NFT contract and deployed to our testnet account. Reference: https://examples.near.org/NFT

We need help with `/sign_url` API. It generates a link to NEAR Wallet with provided transaction details. May be used to redirect user to the wallet and perform a transaction without generation application-specific keys and granting access:
[image]

We have generated approve transaction URL using `/sign_url` API:
[image]

By opening and signing generated approve transaction URL and getting this error:

```
{"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`\n left: `\"mamba11.testnet\"`,\n right: `\"mamba-marketplace-v1.testnet\"`: Unauthorized', /home/gitpod/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/near-contract-standards-3.2.0/src/non_fungible_token/core/core_impl.rs:348:9"}}
```

[image]

Please help us to solve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when i was using `mint` function inside nft_mint(). The solution was to change `mint` function to `internal_mint` according to this example : https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/examples/non-fungible-token/nft/src/lib.rs#L99 , and without checking owner_id at 98 row! Also you will need to change your `near-sdk` version to > 4.0.0 and `near-contract-standarts` to > 4.0.0. And i changed `receiver_id` type from ValidAccountId to AccountId.

Here are docs with description of `internal_mint` and `mint` functions https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-contract-standards/src/non_fungible_token/core/core_impl.rs#L325